# Can I shortcut by using cin >> stringstream::rdbuf()?

Tags: c++, cin, stringstream

I'd started with a safe implementation of some code that reads a string and parses it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
  string work;
  int var1, var2;

  cin >> work;                        // Fill working string from stdin
  stringstream(work) >> var1 >> var2; // Parses as expected.
  cout << var1 << ' ' << var2 << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I thought I'd cut out some extraneous code and it seems to work fine, but I can understand how this might be *bad*.

```
  ...
  stringstream work;
  ...
  cin >> work.rdbuf();  // Fill working string from stdin
  work >> var1 >> var2; // Parses as expected.
  ...
```

Why is it that reading from istream does not overwrite work's buffer in bad ways? What should I be careful about, with this technique?

Comment: in both cases there is a guarantee that the stream is in a valid state if an exception is thrown. certain streams like `fstream` maintain a separate internal buffer different from the one manipulated by `rdbuf` though.

Comment: `std::cin >> var1 >> var2;` reads two int variables without all that wheel-spinning. What problem is that extra stuff supposed to solve?

Comment: Heh... I don't remember the full context anymore, but this was a very simplified extract; I was curious why the buffer would not be overwritten.